# Prevent optimization of text! and json! plugins on requirejs optimization tool

Tags: javascript, requirejs, requirejs-text, requirejs-optimizer

I'm using the following architecture for my multipage requirejs based application.:
https://github.com/requirejs/example-multipage-shim

The repository explains how to optimize the application by running r.js, the command line tool used for this kind of task.

Everything should work fine but my project as some modules that have dependencies that perform HTTP GET request to fetch data from server (wich can be text or json)

This is because some of my jsons and templates used by some pages need to be server-side processed for localization.

**Here is a basic example to show what i'm talking about:**

```
 define( function( require ){

    var appLang = require('json!/pagelang/login'),           //(a)
        loginTemplate = require('text!/template/login'),     //(b)
        module = require('app/model/user'),                  //(c)
        ....
```

An HTTP get request is made to my server localhost/pagelang/login
which returns a json

```
{
   "hash": "translated_value",
    ...
}
```

The same applied for `template/template_name`where an html with it's UI translated into the user language is returned from the server.

By running r.js it attempts to load those locations for an existant directory directory on the server, which obviously, don't exist.

```
Tracing dependencies for: app/main/login
Error: Error: Loader plugin did not call the load callback in the build:
json:
  json!/pagelang/login: Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/pagelang/login'
Module loading did not complete for: app/main/login
```

**So, i would like to prevent the command line tool from optimizing text! and json! modules. Is it possible?**

I checked requirejs build settings but i didn't find the solution for my problem. Any help? 
https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The json plugin uses `if (( config.isBuild && (config.inlineJSON === false || name.indexOf(CACHE_BUST_QUERY_PARAM +'=') !== -1)) || (url.indexOf('empty:') === 0)) {` when the optimiser runs so you have a couple of options.

- Add the build config option `inlineJSON: false`,
- Add `!bust` to the end of the json require. `require('json!/pagelang/login!bust')`, or
- Add the path to the build config option `paths: { "/pagelang/login": "empty:" }`

The text plugin uses `if (config.isBuild && !config.inlineText) {` and `if (url.indexOf('empty:') === 0) {`

- Set the build config option `inlineText: false`, or
- Add the path to the build config option `paths: { "/template/login": "empty:" }`

=================================================================

Update: if you can't get the option `inlineJSON` to work, try using `inlineText`, which seems to cover JSON as well.
Reference: https://github.com/requirejs/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js

Comment: i forgot to mention a special thanks into this question. It was very helpful.